# Maven dependencies for Jena RIOT

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web

Which Maven dependency do I need to parse the formats listed by classes like RDFFormat in Jena?

I have some code that works fine when using `RDFFormat.TURTLE_BLOCKS`, but yields this error upon `RDFFormat.RDFXML_PRETTY`:

```
19:54:08.447 [ERROR]: Error while running batch processor thread pool-2-thread-1: Failed to find a writer factory for RDF/XML/pretty
org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: Failed to find a writer factory for RDF/XML/pretty
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.StreamRDFWriter.getWriterStream(StreamRDFWriter.java:179)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.StreamRDFWriter.write(StreamRDFWriter.java:218)
    at net.sourceforge.ondex.rdf.export.RDFFileExporter.lambda$export$1(RDFFileExporter.java:53)
    at uk.ac.ebi.utils.threading.BatchProcessor.lambda$handleNewTask$0(BatchProcessor.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19:54:09.445 [ERROR]: Error while running batch processor thread pool-2-thread-1: Failed to find a writer factory for RDF/XML/pretty
org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: Failed to find a writer factory for RDF/XML/pretty
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.StreamRDFWriter.getWriterStream(StreamRDFWriter.java:179)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.StreamRDFWriter.write(StreamRDFWriter.java:218)
    at net.sourceforge.ondex.rdf.export.RDFFileExporter.lambda$export$1(RDFFileExporter.java:53)
    at uk.ac.ebi.utils.threading.BatchProcessor.lambda$handleNewTask$0(BatchProcessor.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So, looks like I have to include some dependency. This is happening with Jena 3.6.0.

**EDIT**: I think this is a bug, or at least a case that should be documented better. Just filed an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1634), let's see what Jena guys think.

Comment: `RDFXML_PRETTY` is the same as `RDFXML` which should work out of the box with `apache-jena-libs` (type: `pom`) - latest version is by the way `3.9.0` - more info indeed [online](https://jena.apache.org/download/maven.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AKSW. I've tried that variant, but it's not so simple. I think it's a bug, and I just filed a ticket, see my post's edit.

Comment: maybe you're using the Jena OSGI package? or have any older (transitive) dependency of Jena in your code?

Comment: @AKSW, no, it's actually that there are two different registries of writers, see the Andy's comment at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1634. I'll try what he says and I'll update this SO question.